# Lucas Numbers Matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, lucas-numbers, steady-state

In linear algebra I have an equation $x_n = Ax_0$.  I know the values of $x$ for any given value of $n$, and I know $x_0$.  Both are $2\times 1$ matrices.  How do I solve for $A$?  The answer should be a $2\times2$ matrix with entries $[1 1; 1 0]$.  This is for Lucas Numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf x_n = A \mathbf x_{n-1}\\
\mathbf x_n = A^n \mathbf x_0$

That is:

$\mathbf x_n = \begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\x_{n}\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf x_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}+x_n\\x_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathbf x_{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x_n\\
$

How do you find $A^n$?
Diagonalize $A, A = P^{-1} D P \implies A^n =P^{-1} D^n P$